# Socket.io connection local from internet

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, server, client

I have to make a system using socket.io there is the server in local (without port forwarded) (socket.io listen on the port 6255) and the client (socket.io.js)  on a web server online hosted by hostinger.

I try to communicate between this two server but I have a connection timed out every time.

Connection on the server side : http://pastebin.com/xAFkserq

Connection on the  client side : http://pastebin.com/ZMvbR3hC

Is it possible to communicate between two "networks" ? Or it's just a coding problem ?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing this?

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('connected');
});
```

Also, have you tried following the examples in Socket.IO documentation?

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Working with sockets might be tricky, check if your network is blocking the exchange of messages somehow.

Comment: but I don't want to use express or another http system because the client side is in fact the frontend part so I don't want to have a server that send html file just a "socket.io server"

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `connect` on the client side with socket.io

On the client side simply do: `var socket = io();` to connect back to the server, once the client JS has been served

Edit:

Since you're not using express and intend to just have a socket.io listener, the examples [here](http://socket.io/docs/#using-it-just-as-a-cross-browser-websocket) should provide the information you need

Comment: I have the same problem, a connection timed out :/

Comment: Then you'll have to post the rest of your code. It is unlikely your server is listening if you could not connect.

Comment: You should put that code in the original question. If you are not using express then look at the examples [here](http://socket.io/docs/#using-it-just-as-a-cross-browser-websocket) that are not using express. In this case you may need to use `connect`. It appears that do they not use `listen` on the server side

Comment: I also have this error :  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '***' is therefore not allowed access. I don't know what to do :/